# grails 3.0.6 error when running grails on prompt

Tags: grails, command-line-interface

When i type grails on prompt i get the following output

`PS C:\Users\gunter.amorim> grails.bat --stacktrace --verbose
Usage:
         create-app [NAME] --profile=web
         create-plugin [NAME] --profile=web-plugin

| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3140)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.git.GitProfileRepository.getAllProfiles(GitProfileRepository.groovy:72)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.ListProfilesCommand.handle(ListProfilesCommand.groovy:43)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:177)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.getBaseUsage(GrailsCli.groovy:122)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:166)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:99)
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: null`

I am using jdk1.7.0_67 and grails 3.0.6